# push UIViewController without UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, pagination

I've got a UIViewController with two button, prev and next. When I push these button I re-instantiate the same viewcontroller passing it some variables and then I push it on the UINavigationController with no animation.

With this method my memory is always full cause, as far as i know, it is released only when I pop my viewcontrollers.

So my question is.. how could I implement this behavior? I need to free the memory when I load next (or prev) view controller

Comment: I believe you can use `setViewControllers:Animated:` to set the view controllers on the navigation controller stack. This will allow you to "drop" old navigation controllers you no longer need. Documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html . I've no example code so I've not posted as an answer.

Comment: uhm.. it could works! I will try and i let you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a custom Navigation controller and animate the transitions yourself.

Comment: how could I build a custom navigation controller?

Comment: Subclass UINavigationController and overload the methods to pushViewController with your own custom code. Another option I guess would be to 'unload' your views in viewDidDissappear releasing any memory you don't want to hold.

Comment: I will try with viewDidDisappear, but in the meantime, could you provide me some code to overload pushViewController? Cause I don't know how to prevent keeping all the viewcontrollers on the stack